# ASP.NET Identity - Verify Password Without Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hash, asp.net-identity, md5

**Background**

I am using the

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

framework in an MVC website. I implement all the standard features like password retrieval, email confirmations etc. in the site.

**My Problem**

I want to create a very basic App in Xamarin c#, but I want it to use the database that I have set up with my website, and that - of course - includes verifying passwords.

By my thoughts it should go something like this:

1. User enters login details on phone.
2. Phone hashes password and consumes WCF service which takes hash string as input
3. Returns bool. Depending on hash verification.

I can not use

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

on my Xamarin App.

**Question**

How do I recreate the hash that Asp.Identity uses so I can verify the passwords?

If the case is that I have to consume the WCF with the raw password (Is this safe?) and do the hashing on the service itself - will I be able to use Identity framework? If not then I still have the problem of creating / verifying the hash.

Also if I am way off base with my understanding of these hash functions please feel free to educate me :)

**Extra Info**

The hash functions I have tried give completely different hashes to that of the Identity framework - and in my testing I have found that creating users with exactly the same passwords gives different hashes. (Due to the salt used?)

Answer (score 1):

**Okay I have found a solution**

*Posting for the sake of people with similar problems*

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure) answer by [zespri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284111/zespri). *Upvoted by the way*.

I have decided to consume the WCF with the raw password and username and simply use the function to verify that the answer stated above provides.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify it is this bit of code (Taken from the above link), that I use to verify the password:

```
public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
{
byte[] buffer4;
if (hashedPassword == null)
{
    return false;
}
if (password == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
}
byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
if ((src.Length != 0x31) || (src[0] != 0))
{
    return false;
}
byte[] dst = new byte[0x10];
Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 0x10);
byte[] buffer3 = new byte[0x20];
Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0x11, buffer3, 0, 0x20);
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, dst, 0x3e8))
{
    buffer4 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
}
return ByteArraysEqual(buffer3, buffer4);
}
```