# Does the Identity `SecurityStamp` on a `User` class lessen the need to store the hash salt?

Tags: asp.net, security, hash, asp.net-identity

I've always stored the password hash and salt for most of my authentication sub-systems, but I notice the default `IdentityUser` class only has a hash and a `Security` stamp field, but no salt value.

Has storing the salt value fallen by the wayside, and does `SecurityStamp` add any safety in this regard, or should be extend the user and add a `HashSalt` field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identity stores password hash and salt in the same field in the database. Here is a good explanation how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/809357

As for Security Stamp - it has nothing to do with password or a hash. This only indicates if information about the user have been changed in the database and is compared to the values in auth-cookies. Security Stamp is put into auth-cookie as a claim. Password hash is never present on the cookie.