# How to compare this Salted password when user logs in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cryptography, saltedhash

I've used this method to get salted password. I don't know how I can compare the stored salted password with user entered password when he/she logs in

```
string salt = GetRandomSalt();
 string passwordHash = HashPassword(txtPassword.Text, salt);
 IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, passwordHash);


    public String GetRandomSalt(Int32 size = 12)
    {
        var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var salt = new Byte[size];
        random.GetBytes(salt);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
    }
    public String HashPassword(String password, String salt)
    {
        var combinedPassword = String.Concat(password, salt);
        var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combinedPassword);
        var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }
```

My application is ASP.net MVC 4 and uses identity framework to provide roles and users

I tried using the following code in login form, but it's not working. I guess it's because the manager.Create hashes the salted hash again. How to fix it?

**Login.aspx**

```
  bool pwmatch = VerifyPassword(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);


    public String HashPassword(String password, String salt)
    {
        var combinedPassword = String.Concat(password, salt);
        var sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
        var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(combinedPassword);
        var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    private bool VerifyPassword(string suppliedUserName, string suppliedPassword)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MUSICConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        var user = manager.FindByName(suppliedUserName);
        bool passwordMatch = false;
        string dbPasswordHash = user.PasswordHash;
        int saltSize = 12;
        string salt =dbPasswordHash.Substring(dbPasswordHash.Length - saltSize);
        string hashedPasswordAndSalt =HashPassword(suppliedPassword, salt);
        // Now verify them.
        passwordMatch = hashedPasswordAndSalt.Equals(dbPasswordHash);
        return passwordMatch;
    }
```

Comment: From just looking over the code, it seems like you are appending the hash to the end of the plaintext password and then computing the sha256 hash. You are taking a saltsize of 12 chars after reading the hash from the db - is that right? how are you sure thats what is being stored in your db?

Comment: I'm appending salt at end of plain text and compute sha256 hash. Then reading the salted hash from db. In login page,       string salt =dbPasswordHash.Substring(dbPasswordHash.Length - saltSize);  this finds the salt. then hash the entered password with salt. I dont know if manager.Create used by identity framework is doing some enctryption and hashing when user is created with IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, passwordHash);

Comment: also is        string salt =dbPasswordHash.Substring(dbPasswordHash.Length - saltSize); this correct?

Answer (score 3):

The main idea to use a salt for a specific user/password, but being able to retain the used salt when user logs in again. Here are the logical steps needed to do that:

**To Store a Password**

- Generate a long random salt.
- Prepend the salt to the password and hash it with a standard password hashing function.
- Save both the salt and the hash in the user's database record.

**To Validate a Password**

- Retrieve the user's salt and hash from the database.
- Prepend the salt to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
- Compare the hash of the given password with the hash from the database. If they match, the password is correct. Otherwise, the password is incorrect.

Ref: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Answer (score 1):

Notice here how the default hash implementation in Identity is working
[ASP.NET Identity default Password Hasher, how does it work and is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identity-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure)

ASP.NET Identity already contains a method to verify hashed password - its called [VerifyHashedPassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.108).aspx) you should be able to use this (unless you migrated in a particular way from prior asp.net membership)