# Android register/login user with .Net Identity 2

Tags: android, asp.net-identity, okhttp

I have an Android app with a back-end server running `ASP.NET MVC`. User authentication and authorization in back-end is done with `ASP.NET Identity 2` framework.
How can I securely register/login users from within Android app? In Android app I am using `OkHttp` to communicate with server.

Comment: You can us REST api with in your server. In your mobile use volley and at most, you can encrypt data being send from your device. Try sending passwords in hash form.

Comment: What is the actual hashing mechanism in identity framework? How can I implement that in Java?

Comment: Read this about hashing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/809357 but why would you want to implement it in Java if you are using Identity framework anyway?

Comment: I want to hash password and then encrypt it so that while transferring password, no one can view raw password. So hashing algorithm in Java must be exactly the same as what that Identity2 uses for hashing.