# password History for Identity Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, password-encryption

is there any default implementation for password history? i'm trying to implement that feature on my project with identity so i have added password history table which contain password hashes. when user change password usermanager generate hash for password.

`var passwordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, newPassword);`

if this hash does not inserted in password history table it allow to change password otherwise return error

but the problem is each time when generating hash for the specific password it generate random hashes which cannot be compare also

`var passwordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, newPassword);`

hash differ from

`_userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, request.Token, password);`

generated password hash.

May be i'm trying to do this in wrong way. what was the mistake i have done implementing password history?

thanks

Comment: It shouldn't generate random hashes. It should generate the same hash for the same password every time. Otherwise something is seriously broken.

Comment: i tried with resetting same password hash continuously changing

Comment: Then you did it wrong. Obviously. The same data should hash to the same hash every time. Otherwise it is all pointless. Post your erroneous code.

Comment: @EJP is correct. If the same password didn't always produce the same hash, no one could ever login, as that's part of the authentication process. The password the user enters is hashed and then compared to the hashed password in the database (which is basically exactly the same process you'd follow for your validation).

Comment: Any updates? I've faced the same issue.
`var newPasswordHash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);
var newPasswordHash1 = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);`
Every row returns different value

Answer (score 8):

Different hashes every time - it's how default implementation `IPasswordHasher` works. Look at this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/6104621.

So, for your implementation password history, you can either implement `IPasswordHasher` or just verify a new password with all stored passwords hashes using method

```
PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword);
```

Just for example:

```
var passAlreadyExist = user.UserHistory
                .Select(h => h.PasswordHash)
                .Distinct()
                .Any(hash =>
                {
                    var res = manager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hash, password);
                    return res == PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
                });
```

where `UserHistory` - it's custom table with some user info like *password*, *email*, *name*...