# Is there a way to set Identity-core that do not allow same password when a user is changing the password at the project startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Is there a way to set Identity-core that do not allow same password when a user is changing the password at the project startup ?
i do not want to check it with IF clause , i wanna set in Identity-core options or some where like this to manage it globally at my project( ASP.net core with C#)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have as a function in User class to be access it easy, because password change should be allowed in 1 page only, so the code that checks also can live on that page (model/controller).

**THE EASIEST WAY** is the obvious one - in password change controller you MUST collect OLD password and NEW one as a plain text - so why not just compare them? :D

**Less easy way**: Just use `signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync` in password change controller (if for some reason you dont have old password as a plain text), BEFORE changing pass. If success you would know that new pass is the same.

**The best way**: [checking old passwords to protect from setting the same after first setting new, then resetting to old (the same)] [password History for Identity Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783202/password-history-for-identity-core)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to store the previous password hashes separately in a table. Then
you will need to implement your own password validator and register it which should overwrite the default password validator for asp.net core identity.

1. Implement `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordValidator` as

   ```
   public class MyPasswordValidator: IPasswordValidator
   {
       public Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, string password)
       {
           // custom validation logic
           // search for previous passwords based on user's id and see if they match
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register it in the services. Make sure you place it at after registering all the default asp.net identity identity services.

   ```
   services.AddScoped<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>, MyPasswordValidator>();
   ```

You can also implement an additional property for previous passwords in your `ApplicationUser` class so that all the previous passwords are already present in your `user` variable

Comment: thank you @rabinak. its so helpful. im looking for something like this : services.IdentityCore(options => option.password.length = 8;) in Configuration method 
 at startup file , to force user to have different password at changing password  time

Comment: Hash is DIFFERENT even if pass is the same.. so this is not the answer to compare hashes. I guess best is to try use signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync method with new password [in password change] if success, then forbid that new password.