# Asp.net to Golang migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, go

I need to migrate an application from asp.net to React FrontEnd with a Golang backend.

The Asp.net app is to be decommissioned so I am setting API in Golang and React for the front end.

So this leaves me with the legacy MSSQL database and the records that are existing.

This leads me to the question which is as follows;

Each user in the MSSQL database has a password hash assigned to it, I need to know how that was created so that I can recreate this in Golang. I need this so that I can validate users' passwords using Go and I can also create new users with the same hashing for consistency.

I hope that this is clear.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621950/asp-net-identitys-default-password-hasher-how-does-it-work-and-is-it-secure i think it is ton of work, I would consider exposing ASP.NET API for the login or even expiring every user's password

Comment: also I don't understand "from asp.net to react" part. ASP.NET can be backend for the React frontend

Comment: That is for reference really, i will edit the question to be more clear

Comment: If you need to know how the legacy password hashes were created, review the legacy authentication code.

Answer (score 2):

I Managed to find a library to achieve this.

https://github.com/SuNNjek/identity