Trouble connecting to mysql using ASP.NET
I'm working on a basic CRUD app using C# and React and I seem to be having trouble connecting to my MySQL database. When I register a user, I get an error response message:
"message": "Error creating user: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-manager.users (username, password) VALUES ('test', 'test')' at line 1\r\n
here's the backend
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using dotenv.net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalHost3000", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

DotEnv.Load();
var dbServer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_SERVER");
var dbPort = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_PORT");
var dbDatabase = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_DATABASE");
var dbUser = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_USER");
var dbPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_PASSWORD");

var connectionString = $"server={dbServer};port={dbPort};database={dbDatabase};user={dbUser};password={dbPassword};";

builder.Services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ => new MySqlConnection(connectionString));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("AllowLocalHost3000");
app.UseRouting();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.MapPost("/register", async (User user, MySqlConnection connection) => {
try {
    var q = "INSERT INTO employee_manager.users (`username`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?)";

    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using var cmd = new MySqlCommand(q, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.Username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", user.Password);
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

   return Results.Json(new { StatusCode = 201, Message = "User created successfully" });


} catch (Exception ex) {
    return Results.Json(new { StatusCode = 500, Message = $"Error creating user: {ex}" });
}
finally {
    connection.Close();
}
});

app.Run();

and in case it helps, how I'm requesting
 async function registerHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        try {
          const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/register`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
            credentials: "include",
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
          });
    
          if (response.status === 201) {
            alert("Registration successful! You can now login");
            navigate("/login");
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

I've quadruple checked the .env configuration is correct and that the query string works when used directly in the mysql workbench. I'm guessing this means that I'm not connecting to the database properly?

don't know if it's a typo, but your code shows INSERT INTO employee_manager.users, but the error message shows -manager.users. Note that the code uses an underscore, but the error message shows a hyphen.

I noticed this and it confused me as well. I have however made sure that all the instances of the db name have an underscore and not a hyphen.

Search your code for employee-manager.users; it seems extremely likely that you have a hyphen somewhere in the code (not shown here) and that's causing the issue.

Additionally, storing plaintext passwords in a database is an extremely bad practice and a critical security bug you should fix immediately (if this is anything other than a toy project). (And even if it's a toy project, it's a technique that's worth learning.) For some pointers, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/23633 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/73126492/23633.

I know. Usually I'd hash a password with bcrypt or something similar, but this is my first c# app and I just need to figure out how to get it working properly.

I only have two instances of employee_manager in the entire app so far and that's the query and the dbName in the .env.

I don't know what to tell you, but the SQL in the error message syntax to use near '-manager.users (username, password) VALUES ('test', 'test')' doesn't match the SQL in your example code employee_manager.users (`username`, `password`) VALUES so you must be executing different code than what's displayed here. How are you running and deploying this app? Is it possible you're running an out-of-date Docker container or an old build that has different code?

At the moment I'm running it on my local host. I've discovered that the changes I make to the app are not updated live unless I use hot reload, which I didn't know was a thing. I guess at a certain point I had "-manager" in the string rather than "_manager" and it wasn't updated until I re-ran the app.
